# Show specific data in a message box

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a sheet with many lines witch each one contains a date. I should be able to analyse every date and highlight it in red (already did). But, as it's not a good idea to the person look in all the sheet, I should be able to show in somewhere (I thought of a messagebox) only the past dates.

Like:

- a1 - 12/02/2016
- a2 - 10/02/2016
- a3 - 11/02/2016

Only a2 gets to be red and only it appears in an specific where, facilitating the job to the person.

So far I had been able only to create a msgBox, not anything else. Also, do you guys have any suggestion? I'm also thinking abt creating another sheet, and uploading it with the red data OR in the same sheet, just showing a list of what is red.
Do you guys know how to display the specific data in the messagebox? I'm kinda stuck. If not, do u have any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Each time you highlight the data in red, save the data to a javascript list. Then use Browser.msgBox(list). If you're highlighting the data in more than one call (as in from multiple onEdit triggers), then you'll need to save the data using cache or properties service.

There's also nothing wrong with storing the data in another sheet. Just to note, it's most efficient to add data to a sheet in one go, instead of adding each value one at a time.

Comment: I see. Sadly I'm not able to get the data from the other cell. Look. If I get the color red on C3, then I should be able to get the value from A3. But nvm, i'll find out

Comment: i don't think i fully understand your situation or where the hangup is. Are you saying that you need to scan the sheet for all the red colored cells and show that to the user?

Comment: ya, problem solved buddy. I'm coloring with conditional formatting and then get the values. Would u like to see this piece of code?